# Django-Import-Export - How to Import while "ignoring" __str__ method from Model

Tags: django-models, django-admin, django-import-export

I have the following model:

```
class Code(models.Model):
   project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
   variant = models.CharField(max_length=1)

   class Meta:
      unique_together = ('project', 'code', 'variant',)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.code + self.variant
```

My code in admin.py - note that this is just the basic code - does not use ModelResource - my attempt to use the ModelResource method to "handle" the str method from the model has not been successful.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportMixin

class CodeAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Code', 'Variant')

admin.site.register(Code, CodeAdmin)
```

When trying to import - using admin - I get the following error as a result of the **str** method in the Code model.

```
    Line number: 1 - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' 
None, 1, 700, a
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 464, in import_row
 row_result.object_repr = force_text(instance)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 76, in force_text
 s = six.text_type(s)
 File "C:\GitHub\WebApps\sidProject\sidApp\models.py", line 58, in __str__
 return self.Code + self.Variant
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

My question - How do I "ignore" the **str** in this case. It seems that is being done in the django-import-export sample code using the below ModelResource code but I couldn't get it to work I my case:

```
def for_delete(self, row, instance):
    return self.fields['name'].clean(row) == ''
```

Any help or an example somewhere that I missed will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 model fields were just being concatenated using +. Just followed the method as outlined on the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/).

```
return '%s%s' % (self.Code_code, self.Variant)
```

Problem solved! Lesson learned maybe even - gotta think about the lesson learned though.